# Working with files in c

Tags: c++, file

How do i remove every char which is not a letter from a string
From a string `a,f,4,h,b`,
I need an output `afhbi`.
Attention take in consider that I don't want the commas and other similar signs.
This is my code so far and it is not working , any tips?

```
while((fgets(str,30,fpointer))!=NULL)
{ //i get a string

    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)//going thru the string
    if(isalpha(str[i])){strcat(Need,str[i]);}
      //if the char is alpha put it in a new  string called Need
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `strcat` to add a char to an array. That's for appending one string on to another. Just insert the char in the array.

```
int j = 0;    // Index of the new string
for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {   //going thru the string
    if(isalpha(str[i])) {
        Need[j++] = str[i];
    }
}
Need[j] = 0;   // Make sure you terminate the new string
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this using memmove instead.  First copy your string in Need;

```
Need = strdup(str);
p = Need;
q = str;
while (*q) {
    if (!isalpha(*q)) {
        len = strlen(p); 
        memmove(p, p + 1, len); // this will move the NULL terminator too
    } else {
        p++;
    }
    q++;
}
```

Now, Need is all cleaned up of the ugly non-characters!